# Relating factors based on conclusions on 2 distinct groups?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, group-differences

I determine that Team A achieves higher customer satisfaction scores than Team B with wilcoxn rank sum test. A customer satisfaction score is calculated from different sized groups of customers, and the different sized groups of customers can be repeated in the data. Each team will never have the same groups of customers. It is inconclusive that the size (number of people within a group) between these teams are significantly different with wilcoxn rank sum test.

**Can I assert that it is inconclusive that the size is a contributing factor to the satisfaction scores of the teams?**
If not, what can I do to assert that the size is or isn't a factor to the satisfaction scores of the different teams?